# Yodlee Aggregation API - Opt Out of Sharing Data

Tags: yodlee, plaid

My team is building an app that will require users to connect their financial institution accounts and we've been investigating Yodlee's Developer Platform to help us do so. Seems like a great service, but I've read some dodgy articles in the press about how Yodlee also aggregates and sells that information for a variety of purposes.

Is it possible to opt out of allowing Yodlee to do this? Or does Yodlee require you to share that info in order to use their API services? Do other services like Plaid also do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can't speak for Yodlee, but Plaid (where I work!) offers bank account connections and data services, and we don't sell our data to third parties.